# Как написать бегущую строку

Tags: java, android, html

Дело в том что у меня есть плеер и над ним должна идти бегущая строка. Перепробовал все возможные варианты. Такой вариант `android:ellipsize="marquee"` с `TextView` если видео не играет работает нормально, как только заиграет видео то все, он начинает стоять на месте и трястись. То есть тупо дергается на месте.
Попробовал на `WebView`, `html <marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' scrollamount=5>` Он работает только подлагивая каждую миллисекунду. Но двигается в левую сторону.

UPD: На телефоне webWiew работает без лагов и гладко. Только на Android Приставке так лагает.

Как быть, есть ли еще другие варианты помимо этих?

Comment: может либа, [вроде этой](https://github.com/lopspower/AutoScrollTextView)?

Comment: Да так тоже пробовал, и свой кастомный TextView, без толку(

Comment: Как вариант закрыть TextView слева и справа получая "окно", теперь можно просто сделать анимацию перемещения TextView слева направо - вот и бегущая строка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать отдельный класс, производный от TextView, реализуйте 3 метода **onFocusChanged, onWindowFocusChanged, isFocused**, чтобу TextView был все время в фокусе.

```
@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    if(focused)
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
    if(focused)
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
}

@Override
public boolean isFocused() {
    return true;
}
```

Ссылка на оригинальный ответ [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827751/is-there-a-way-to-make-ellipsize-marquee-always-scroll).